# Faster way to copy vector elements to different structure of vector C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a one dimension vector of integer that stores table data. Which I want to transform into a multidimensional vector (e.g. a vector of int vectors).

This is what I tried:

```
std::vector<int> lin_table = {1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4}
std::vector<std::vector<int>> multi_table;
int num_cols = 4;
for (int column = 0; column < num_cols; column++)
{
   std::vector<int> temp_column;
   for(int element = column; element < lin_table.size(); element += num_cols)
   {
       temp_column.push_back(lin_table.at(element));
   }
   multi_table.push_back(temp_column);
}
```

This is working fine, but I would like to know if there is any faster way to do it?

Comment: How do you even know that this code is both slower than it could be and a bottleneck in your process?

Comment: @Andrew Henle he may have profiled it. And there's nothing wrong with wanting to know how to do this kind of operation effeciently. It's already not bad, but at the very least there's some extra allocation going on which is more than trivial to eliminate. It could also simply be an `std::array` of `std::array`s, if the op doesn't need dynamic allocation down the road. Although truthfully this would be a better question for the code review stack exchange.

Comment: Why would you want to split it up in the first place? Creating a 2d-view into the first vector seems like the better option.

Comment: Besides: You have an error. `temp_column` does not have the correct type.

Comment: If you want speed, don't use `lin_table.at(element)`, use `lin_table[element]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a one dimension vector of integer that stores table data. Which I want to transform into a multidimensional vector (e.g. a vector of int vectors).

Since you insist on performance, as already stated many times here before, it is better to create a class that wraps around a `std::vector` which *emulates* what a two-dimensional vector would do.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Vec2DWrapper {
    std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<T>> vec_;
    size_t rows_;

public:
    using value_type = T;
    Vec2DWrapper(std::vector<T>& vec, size_t const rows)
     : vec_(std::ref(vec)), rows_(rows) {
    }
    T& operator()(size_t const x, size_t const y) {
        return vec_.get()[x * rows_ + y];
    }
    std::vector<T>& get_vector() const { return vec_.get(); }

};
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// ...

int main() {
    std::vector<int> lin_table { 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4 };

    // Bind the 'lin_table' vector to the class
    Vec2DWrapper<int> vec2d(lin_table, 4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            std::cout << vec2d(j, i) << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nik There was a little problem with the code before because of `rows_(rows_)`, I have updated it now. So do note that.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `vector<vector<int>>`. Use a custom class that maps a 2D matrix onto a 1D vector. This way you can move the original vector. Even if you need to copy, it will probably still be faster because it does a single allocation+memcpy, and it's cache friendly:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

template <class Vector>
class Vec2D {
private:
    std::size_t mWidth = 0, mHeight = 0;
    Vector mData;

public:
    Vec2D(int height, int width) 
        : mWidth(width)
        , mHeight(height)
        , mData(width * height)
    {}

    Vec2D(int height, Vector vec) noexcept
        : mWidth(vec.size() / height)
        , mHeight(height)
        , mData(std::move(vec))
    {}

    auto& get(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) noexcept {
        return mData[mHeight * col + row]; // mix is intentional
    }

    auto& get(std::size_t row, std::size_t col) const noexcept {
        return mData[mHeight * col + row]; // mix is intentional
    }

    auto width() const noexcept {
        return mWidth;
    }

    auto height() const noexcept {
        return mHeight;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> lin_table = {1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4};

    Vec2D v2d{4, std::move(lin_table)};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v2d.height(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < v2d.width(); ++j) {
            std::printf("%d ", v2d.get(i, j));
        }
        std::putchar('\n');
    }
}
```